# Best reference on deconvolutions?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, statistical-inference, estimation, deconvolution

Can you point me towards the best reference in your opinion for learning about  deconvolutions? Preferably this would be from a statistics standpoint, discussing how to estimate a convoluted density when the other densities are not known, but are estimated from i.i.d. data. Is there a textbook or a very well written paper that discusses estimators, and presents consistency and inference results for deconvolution estimators?

If it helps, I do not understand anything about physics, nor time/frequency domains or other such language, so a text that is too geared towards engineers will go over my head. I do have an advanced background in math and statistics though.